# how to check whether RBAC is enabled, using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rbac

I'm trying to install a helm package on a kubernetes cluster which allegedly has RBAC disabled.
I'm getting a permission error mentioning `clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io`, which is what I'd expect if RBAC was *enabled*.

Is there a way to check with `kubectl` whether RBAC really is disabled?

What I've tried:

- `kubectl describe nodes --all-namespaces | grep -i rbac` : nothing comes up
- `kubectl describe rbac --all-namespaces | grep -i rbac` : nothing comes up
- `kubectl config get-contexts | grep -i rbac` : nothing comes up
- `k get clusterroles` it says "No resources found", not an error message. So does that mean that RBAC *is* enabled?
- `kuebctl describe cluster` isn't a thing

I'm aware that maybe this is the [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because it's possible the helm package I'm installing is expecting RBAC to be enabled. But still, I'd like to know how to check whether or not it is enabled/disabled.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You can check this by executing the command `kubectl api-versions`; if RBAC is enabled you should see the API version `.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1`.

In AKS, the best way is to check the cluster's resource details at [resources.azure.com](https://resources.azure.com).
If you can spot `"enableRBAC": true`, your cluster has RBAC enabled.
Please note that existing non-RBAC enabled AKS clusters cannot currently be updated for RBAC use. (thanks @DennisAmeling for the clarification)

Comment: For Azure (AKS) this is a bit more tricky. While the `kubectl api-versions` indeed returns `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1`, the `kubectl get clusterroles` doesn't return default `system:` prefixed roles.

The best way to check for AKS is to check the cluster's resource details, e.g. at https://resources.azure.com. If "enableRBAC": true, your cluster has RBAC enabled.  Existing non-RBAC enabled AKS clusters [cannot currently be updated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/aad-integration) for RBAC use.

So if you want to enable RBAC on AKS, you have to create a new cluster.

Comment: @DennisAmeling please consider adding this as an independent answer, none of the others worked for me because I was on Azure and difference in RBAC behaviour is very unexpected.

Comment: How about `kubectl api-versions | grep rbac`?

Comment: Another option for Azure AKS is: `az aks list` and look for "enableRbac": true or false

Answer (score 24):

I wish there was a better way but what I use is:

```
$ kubectl cluster-info dump | grep authorization-mode
```

If you can execute it you should either see `RBAC` listed there or not, and if you don't have the permissions to do it, well, chances are that RBAC is enabled.

Comment: I tried that. `dump` [doesn't work](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/65221) for me.

Comment: After [downgrading my kubectl](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/65221) I can now run `cluster-info dump`. I tried this on a cluster which definitely has RBAC enabled, and there was no output.

Comment: If the above command returns no value and no error, what does it means?

Comment: Leave the second part (the grep command) out for now, what do you see?

Answer (score 12):

For Azure (AKS) this is a bit more tricky. While the `kubectl api-versions` command indeed returns `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1`, the `kubectl get clusterroles` command doesn't return the default `system:` prefixed roles.

The best way to check for AKS is to check the cluster's resource details, e.g. at [resources.azure.com](https://resources.azure.com). If `"enableRBAC": true`, your cluster has RBAC enabled. Existing non-RBAC enabled AKS clusters [cannot currently be updated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/aad-integration) for RBAC use. So if you want to enable RBAC on AKS, you'll have to create a new cluster.

Answer (score 12):

For Azure (AKS) I think Azure CLI works well.

```
az resource show -g <resource group name> -n <cluster name> --resource-type Microsoft.ContainerService/ManagedClusters --query properties.enableRBAC
```

It is basically the same thing as using [resources.azure.com](https://resources.azure.com), but I find it quicker to use the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: The use case I had was that Azure claimed my cluster had RBAC *disabled*, but it behaved exactly like it would if RBAC was *enabled*. I wanted to check whether Azure had a bug. (AKS is full of lots of severe bugs, so it's a reasonable suspicion.)

Comment: You can also use the cli aks command, e.g.: `az aks show -g <resource group name> -n <cluster name> --query enableRbac`

Answer (score 3):

**None of the other presented solutions are universal or can be relied upon.**

They work in some places but not others.  The only reliable way is to actually test the RBAC API and see if it enforces the permissions.  You can do that like this:

Save the following into a file named: `no-permissions.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: no-permissions
  namespace: default
```

Apply it with `kubectl apply -f no-permissions.yaml`

Now, because there is no role binding for this service account, it can't do anything when RBAC is enabled. This changes when RBAC is disabled.

You can therefore use `kubectl` to determine if the access permissions are enforced

**For example:**

**RBAC off**

```
> kubectl auth can-i get cm -A --as=system:serviceaccount:default:no-permissions
yes
```

**RBAC on**

```
> kubectl auth can-i get cm -A --as=system:serviceaccount:default:no-permissions
no
```

In practice I think you might need to create a Role and a RoleBinding as well and test a few other actions, just to be certain.  But this is the general idea.

**In summary.  RBAC will enforce permissions when available and enabled in the cluster.  If it's not doing so, then it's not enabled.**

Answer (score 2):

Option #1:
If you have access to master node then login into and check below

```
ps -aef | grep -i apiserver
The options should have --authorization-mode=RBAC otherwise RBAC not enabled.
```

Option #2:

```
kubectl get clusterroles | grep -i rbac
```

Comment: With option 2, just to clarify:
If there is no output, then RBAC is disabled?

I expect the cluster to not know what `clusterroles` are if RBAC is disabled. But I get "No resources found" on one cluster, and on another I get a long list of roles including `system:auth-delegator` and `system:controller:clusterrole-aggregation-controller`, but excluding anything mentioning `rbac`.

Comment: I just spun up a cluster with RBAC enabled and option 2 results in no output.

Comment: if the scond command "kubectl get clusterroles | grep -i rbac" returns no value and no error, what does it means?

Comment: like @falsePockets i too get no output from method #2 above.

Comment: what is the output of `kubectl api-versions` ? In my cluster with RBAC enabled the o/p contains `.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1`

Answer (score 1):

For AKS if you have multiple clusters (and you do, right?) you can get a tabulated list of `enabledRbac` properties with

```
: my-desktop:~:0; az aks list | jq -r '.[]|"Cluster: \(.name) Resource-group: \(.resourceGroup) Enabled: \(.enableRbac) "' | column -t
Cluster:  test                  Resource-group:  dev-stack   Enabled:  false
Cluster:  ftx-cluster-1         Resource-group:  prod        Enabled:  true
Cluster:  ftx-cluster-2         Resource-group:  prod        Enabled:  true
Cluster:  taskrabbit            Resource-group:  newprod     Enabled:  true
```

Answer (score 0):

az aks show -g resource_group_of_your_AKS -n your-cluster-name --query enableRbac -o tsv